# Failed to install and open jupyter both in JuliaPro and anaconda on Mac

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I installed JuliaPro 1.0 and Pkg.build("IJulia') but failed. I also installed anaconda and try this way to open jupyter use IPython kernel but failed again. I even tried to directly run code " jupyter notebook" in terminal but failed as well.

[image]

[image]